# Android studio random I'm getting an error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, ide

**//ENG**

I don't know English, I may have mistakes, sorry.

Hello there...

I want to random text, but somewhere there was a problem.

Where the problem is located

**//TR**

Merhaba...

Random text yapmak istiyorum ama bir yerde sorun çıktı.

Sorunun bulunduğu yer

Kodlarımın tamamı ise aşağıdadır.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: remove the first line from `strings.xml` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a empty line in the start of the strings.xml file remove the empty line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Remove this line from top

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">JarTest</string>
<string-array name="status">
    <item>Available</item>
    <item>Busy</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: Ahhahahaa thanks..    I'm getting an error here too: / random text

Comment: String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.name);
     Random rand = new Random();
     int  n = rand.nextInt(names.length()-1);
     tw1.setText(names[n]);